# Get pose from bones that get motion from parent objects

Tags: rigging, bones

I have various rigs with bones following physics items using the Child Of constraint with Set inverse (although this issue isn't really specific to that constraint, but to any issue where bones follow objects in any sort of way.) What I want to do is run my simulation, which puts my rig into a certain pose, then save this position as a pose that I can later restore without running physics.

However, I cannot do this, as bones that inherit rotation or location from parent objects do not show any rot or loc changes, so there is nothing to save. But there must be some way to get the current positions and convert them to a pose?

Comment: You can walk the bone's parent-tree up until there is no parent and accumulate the total transformation I think

Comment: You're looking for a kind of "pose baking" no? I don't think Blender has this function yet. It would be a really great tool, for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Bake the pose into an Action using visual keying:

- Pose > Animation > Bake Action
- You can bake 1 frame by setting the start and end to the same frame
- Set Visual Keying ON
- Set Clear Constraints ON
- Set Clear Parents ON
- Bake Data to Pose

Now you should have an action with desired pose keyed.

You can load this action into Pose library (make it suitable for pose library with help ring icon)